# Converting for loops to recursion [finding consecutive weekdays]

Tags: python, date, recursion

I have a couple of nested for loops that try to find consecutive and non-consecutive weekdays to print them as a string. Here's a working loop example:

```
week = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
days1 = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Fri', 'Sat']

def is_consecutive(d1, d2):
    for i in range(0, len(week) - 1):
        if d1 == week[i] and d2 == week[i + 1]:
            return True
    return False

def get_week_string(days):
    string = ''
    i = 0
    next_day = 1
    while i < len(days):
        if i < len(days) - 1 and is_consecutive(days[i], days[i + 1]):
            for j in range(i, len(days) - 1):
                if is_consecutive(days[j], days[j + 1]):
                    next_day = j + 1
                else:
                    break
            string = string + days[i] + " - " + days[next_day] + ", "
            i = next_day + 1
        else:
            string = string + days[i] + ", "
            i += 1

    if string[-2:] == ', ':
        string = string[:-2]
    return string

print get_week_string(days1)
# prints Mon - Wed, Fri - Sat
```

I initially tried to solve this with recursion but failed miserably. Now that I have an working example, I've been taking a few more stabs at it but really can get my head around it. My thoughts of making it work is something like:

```
def recursive_weekdays(days, index):
    # Base case
    if index == len(days) - 1:
        return days[index]

    if is_consecutive(days[index], days[index + 1]):
        return days[index] + " - " + recursive_weekdays(days, index + 1)

    # ... blank here :(
    # can't figure out more :/

print recursive_weekdays(days, 0)
```

Any help in figuring this out will not only make me happy, it will also allow me to sleep tonight as I can't get my mind off it :P

EDIT: Here's some test cases.

```
days1 = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Fri', 'Sat']
days2 = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
days3 = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Sun']
days4 = ['Wed','Thu', 'Sun']
days5 = ['Wed','Fri', 'Sat']

days1 -> Mon - Wed, Fri - Sat
days2 -> Mon - Wed, Fri - Sun
days3 -> Mon - Tue, Sun
days4 -> Wed - Thu, Sun
days5 -> Wed, Fri - Sat
```

Comment: Could you provide a couple of test cases and expected output for each?

Comment: sure, added as an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work for all cases (though not heavily tested)

```
week = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
days1 = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Fri', 'Sat']
days2 = ['Mon', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
days3 = ['Mon', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Sat', 'Sun']

def is_consecutive(d1, d2):
    for i in range(0, len(week) - 1):
        if d1 == week[i] and d2 == week[i + 1]:
            return True
    return False


def recursive_weekdays(days, index, in_range=False):
    # Base case
    if index == len(days) - 1:
        return days[index]

    if is_consecutive(days[index], days[index + 1]):
        if not in_range:
            return days[index] + " - " + recursive_weekdays(days, index + 1, True)
        else:
            return recursive_weekdays(days, index + 1, in_range)

    return days[index] + ", " + recursive_weekdays(days, index + 1)

print recursive_weekdays(days1, 0)
print recursive_weekdays(days2, 0)
print recursive_weekdays(days3, 0)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Mon - Wed, Fri - Sat
Mon, Wed - Sun
Mon, Wed - Thu, Sat - Sun
```

The trick here is to only return a value after `-` when you are no longer in a range of consecutive days.

**EDIT**
Here are the output values from your test cases:

```
Mon - Wed, Fri - Sat
Mon - Wed, Fri - Sun
Mon - Tue, Sun
Wed - Thu, Sun
Wed, Fri - Sat
```

Comment: Wow, awesome. Nice touch with the in_range!